# How to properly order the collection 'asc'

Tags: php, laravel

Im trying to order 'asc' the collection below but its not working with the sortBy collection method. Do you know how to properly achieve that?

```
 $topCategories  =  PostCategory::pluck('category_name', 'category_icon')->toArray();
        $topCategories =  collect($postInformation['categories']['data'])->map(function ($postCategory) {
            return
                $postCategory['name']['en'];
        })->sortBy('category_name')->toArray();
```

`dd($topCategories)` shows like:

```
^ array:12 [▼
  0 => "Testing category"
  1 => "category 2"
  ...
]
```

But the category 2 should appear first.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the code with the sortBy('category_name'). Thanks

Comment: Could you add a sample of the data you are using? Also, the first line is irrelevant as it is since you are not using the variable and then overriding it right after

Comment: In your map function you are just returning a value. So, after that, the collection will only have keyless values. You could simply use `->sort()` then.

Comment: there is no `category_name`, you just have an array of values, there are no 'columns' at this point

Comment: Try this one, `sortByDesc("category_name")->reverse();`

Comment: This is correct, upper `T` sorts before lower `c`. I'm not sure offhand if Laravel/Eloquent (or your database) offers a case-insensitive sort. You might have to send it to an array first, and then use something like natcasesort() in PHP.

Comment: Like this it doesn't work with reverse it shows simply from the array index 11 to 0 instead of 0 to 11.

Comment: Thanks, it works with just sort().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can order it in the actual query:

```
$topCategories  =  PostCategory::->orderBy('category_name', DESC")->pluck('category_name', 'category_icon')->toArray();
```

Which is the better way, because you want need to iterate over each entity in the collection, but still if you want you can use as a function on the collection:

```
sortByDesc("category_name")
```